# Два разных значения на одну команду

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

При запуске указал значение приветствия:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Приветствую, старый друг ')
```

После приветствия и процесса использования бота мне необходимо именно командой /`start` вернуться в главное меню, но когда пишу /`start` выскакивает приветствие.

Как изменить значение команды старт после приветствия?